# Software required to automate test cases using WatiN

Tags: watin

Can anybody please tell me which softwares are required to automate tests of a .NET web application using WatiN.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any unit test framework like NUnit will let you do it. If you want to test against the development web server, that's slightly trickier, but possible.

Reference **WebDev.WebHost.dll** (in the GAC, but can be extracted and referenced on its own as it has no non-framework dependencies) in your unit test, then you have use the `Server` class it exposes to fire up a development web server. This is the server fired up by the development webserver executable, but this doesn't give you a neat shutdown option - the `Server` class however does!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Watin and MBUnit. MBUnit has a really good test runner called Gallio and is easy to work with.

http://www.gallio.org/